# Object getting displaced while animating - SVG

Tags: svg, animation, path

I am trying to animate an image along a path in SVG. The object does get animated along the defined path but away from its intended position. I am not able too see as to what's wrong with the code. Hope someone would come to my rescue. Thanks in advance.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<svg version="1.1" id="Layer_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
     width="300px" height="400px">
<path id="fave" fill="#F57C00" d="M102.539,32.054c-0.107-4.268-3.523-7.711-7.775-7.863c-0.101-0.004-0.199-0.006-0.299-0.006
    s-0.197,0.002-0.298,0.006c-2.815,0.102-5.263,1.645-6.625,3.91c-1.364-2.266-3.812-3.809-6.626-3.91
    c-0.1-0.004-0.198-0.006-0.298-0.006c-0.099,0-0.198,0.002-0.298,0.006c-4.254,0.152-7.668,3.596-7.776,7.9
    c-0.002,0.068-0.002,0.139-0.002,0.207c0,0.1,0,0.1,0,0.207c0.104,8.7,6.7,16.3,15,20.5c8.284-4.215,14.894-11.814,14.997-20.504
    c0.003-0.068,0.003-0.139,0.003-0.207s0-0.194-0.042-0.24H102.539z">
    <animateMotion  fill="freeze" calcMode="paced" restart="always" additive="replace" dur="0.5s" accumulate="none">
        <mpath  xlink:href="#favepath"></mpath>
    </animateMotion>
</path>
<path id="favepath" fill="none" stroke="#000000" stroke-miterlimit="10" d="M64.075,138.9l23.467-85.896"/>
</svg>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want it to animate along the path itself you need to change the `d` of `#fave`.

It wasn't clear *how* you wanted to do it, so I changed the initial two values of the [`Moveto`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/d) (M) from `M102.539,32.054` to `M0,0` to get [this result](http://jsfiddle.net/zoc2y07L/1/) which animates it from the right edge.  For more information about that attribute, check out [this useful article](http://www.vanseodesign.com/web-design/svg-paths-line-commands/).

You should read some specs on the properties and attributes of the SVG elements you're using so you can better understand what's going on.